# How to avoid multiple running instances of same handler function when running it from editor?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm doing simple handler script that gets appended to `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post`.

Every time I do a changes to it and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> it registers itself again with a new version. after a bit I have 10 of the scripts running happily on every frame change.

How can I get rid of the old running versions without closing and reopening Blender, which seems to be the only option now?

I tried adding unregistering with `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove()` but that is just throwing an error as if my script wasn't on the list. while at the same time `print(bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post)` is showing my function name there in growing numbers :)

so, what's the best practice developing and running these?

thanks.

.b

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In simple cases when you're not having to deal with other handlers, you can clear all handlers before adding new ones:

```
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
```

However for projects which are already using handlers, you may not want to remove everyone *elses* handlers, and instead replace only a handlers the script added.

Currently we don't have a convenient way to handle this, or at least Python doesn't make it so easy to reference a function defined in a previous execution.

This example script shows how the functions name and module can be used, `append_function_unique` is a function to append and remove previous instances.

```
import bpy

def append_function_unique(fn_list, fn):
    """ Appending 'fn' to 'fn_list',
        Remove any functions from with a matching name & module.
    """
    fn_name = fn.__name__
    fn_module = fn.__module__
    for i in range(len(fn_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        if fn_list[i].__name__ == fn_name and fn_list[i].__module__ == fn_module:
            del fn_list[i]
    fn_list.append(fn)


def my_function(scene):
    print(scene)

def register():
    append_function_unique(bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post, my_function)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note: This is isn't such a problem for modules (add-ons or scripts you import). However scripts you run directly will use a module name of `__main__`. This means if you run multiple scripts directly, there may be function naming collisions - which is why this solution isn't ideal.

Comment: @basse If this answer has solved your question then consider 'accepting' the answer by clicking the 'tick' next to it. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

While developing in the text editor I tend to use `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()` to remove all handlers, but this may conflict with other scripts as it won't just remove the functions you appended.

If you want to use `.remove()` then you need to specify the function that you originally appended to the handler. E.g. if you originally did: `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_function_name)` you would do `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_function_name)` to remove it.

Comment: thanks, the bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_function_name) I tried to use, but all I got was error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: @basse I think maybe if you use `clear()` to clear everything out then you will be able to use `remove()` after that.

Comment: An important node, `my_function_name` must be a string literal like `"my_function"`, or a name of a variable holding the string of a function. It can't be the name of a function, meaning a 'pointer' to the function, because when you run a new script, this will be a new function, with a different identity, therefore it will not be found in the list of handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide a simple way to remove an item from handlers list using shallow copy of list of handlers:

```
for func in bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post[:]:
    if func.__name__ == 'your_funciton_name':
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(func)
```