# draw text always face the viewer in 3D view

Tags: scripting

I'd like to write a script to draw some text in 3D view, and I need it always face the viewer, how can I achieve this?

**update:**
My own answer as below.

Comment: What have you got so far? Where are you stuck and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: What do you mean by blf?

Comment: Do you expect someone to write a script for you, or have you started working on one? It would be useful if you share what you have so far, and explain what precisely is giving you trouble.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Sorry for my unclear question, I've update it.

Comment: You should post that as an answer bellow instead, preferably with a short description of what you did wrong, and how you fixed it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos OK, but any clue of the documentation for types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add()?

Comment: No, Official info seems to be missing https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for all of you comments, and sorry for my rough question.

But I guess I have found the answer:

I've used wrong arguement for the `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add()` function. `'POST_PIXEL'` shold be used here as the 4th argument, but `'POST_VIEW'` was used. I guess `'POST_PIXEL'` is for **2D** text, and `'POST_VIEW'` is for **3D** text.

Code and screenshoot as below:

```
import blf
import bgl
import bpy

RED = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
GREEN = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

position_1 = (50, 50, 0)
position_2 = (0, 0, 0)

def draw(position, color):
    blf.position(0, *position)
    blf.size(0, 20, 72)
    bgl.glColor3f(*color)
    blf.draw(0, "hello,world")

_handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, RED), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
_another_handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_2, GREEN), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

[image: screenshoot for result]

**update:**

I've asked someone in our community, and I was given some tips about the **3rd** argument, which maybe represent for **region type** and enumerate in `'WINDOW'`, `'HEADER'`, `'CHANNELS'`, `'TEMPORARY'`, `'UI'`, `'TOOLS'`, `'TOOL_PROPS'`, `'PREVIEW'`.

Code and screenshoot as below for your reference:

```
import blf
import bgl
import bpy

RED = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
GREEN = (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
BLUE = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

position_1 = (0, 0, 0)

def draw(position, color, text):
    blf.position(0, *position)
    blf.size(0, 20, 72)
    bgl.glColor3f(*color)
    blf.draw(0, text)

_handle_1 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, RED, 'WINDOW'), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_2 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, GREEN, 'HEADER'), 'HEADER', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_3 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, ((100, 0, 0), BLUE, 'CHANNELS'), 'CHANNELS', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_4 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, ((250, 0, 0), RED, 'TEMPORARY'), 'TEMPORARY', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_5 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, GREEN, 'UI'), 'UI', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_6 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, BLUE, 'TOOLS'), 'TOOLS', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_7 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, RED, 'TOOL_PROPS'), 'TOOL_PROPS', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_8 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, ((400, 0, 0), GREEN, 'PREVIEW'), 'PREVIEW', 'POST_PIXEL')
_handle_1 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (position_1, RED, 'WINDOW'), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

[image: another screenshoot]

But I‘m still confused about the `draw_handler_add` funciton. I've read the [api documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=draw_handler_add#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add) for this, but is shows "Undocumented". 
Anyone can help me, or explain it for me?

Comment: I'm sure you've got this figured out by now, but I think this link would be handy here.   By calling draw_handler_add you are providing the instructions which are used every time the SpaceView3D needs to be redrawn ( due to a zoom, pan, window resize etc ). The problem then becomes how to [cancel these instructions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75612/how-do-you-remove-a-draw-handler-after-its-been-added).