# Selection Event for F-Curve in Graph Editor

Tags: python, graph-editor, fcurves, select

I'm trying to catch an event when an F-Curve is selected in my add-on. I've added a handler to [bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post) where I'm iterating through [bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph.updates](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html#bpy.types.Depsgraph.updates), however, nothing appears to be triggered for F-Curve selections.

```py
def selection_change_handler(scene):
    for u in bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph.updates:
        print(u)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(selection_change_handler)
```

I was thinking that I could somehow subscribe to `msgbus` with [bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html#bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna), but I'm not sure if/how this would work with every `FCurve` in a `Scene`.

```py
subscribe_to = bpy.types.FCurve.path_resolve("select", False)
#TypeError: descriptor 'path_resolve' for 'bpy_struct' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

I also tried adding a draw handler to the Graph Editor, but I've been unsuccessful in getting the context for this correct with a multiple file add-on. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76020/81083

Can anyone tell me how I can listen for F-Curve selection updates? Thank you!

Comment: i did some research on this for a day. apparently it is not possible.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you for your efforts!